# Extracting Features from VGG

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, caffe

I want to extract features from images in MS COCO dataset using a fine-tuned VGG-19 network.

However, it takes about 6~7 seconds per image, roughly 2 hours per 1k images. (even longer for other fine-tuned models)

There are 120k images in MS COCO dataset, so it'll take at least 10 days.

Is there any way that I can speed up the feature extraction process?

Comment: Using CPU_Only and multi-core processing, an individual image will take 0.7~1.2 (pre-fetching can lead to more rapid process) seconds on average. There is no way to reduce the computational time, as this is the place where GPUs fulfill their own destiny.

Comment: @Shai I'm not sure how to enable gpu for feature extraction as it is being done by a command: ./build/tools/extract_features.bin caffemodel-file prototxt-file fc7 dest_dir #batch lmdb Is there a way to enable gpu on command?

Comment: @Saeed Is it possible using just the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not just a command. First you must check whether your GPU is powerful enough to wrestle with deep CNNs. Knowing your GPU model can answer this question.

Second, you have to compile and build Caffe framework with CUDA and GPU-enabled (CPU_Only disabled) in the Makefile.config (or CMakeLists.txt).

Passing all required steps (installing Nvidia Driver, installing CUDA and etc.) you can build caffe for GPU-use. Then by passing the GPU_Device_ID in your command-line you can benefit from speed provided by them.

Follow [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Install-Caffe-on-EC2-from-scratch-(Ubuntu,-CUDA-7,-cuDNN)) link for building Caffe using GPU.

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you very much! Could you also let me know how to find the GPU_Device_ID and how to insert it in command line? (which -option etc.)

Comment: @ytrewq That depends on how many GPUs you have on your machine. If only one GPU, its is ID is simply 0. for feature extraction.bin you simple put "GPU 0" at the end of your command. However, check out the documentations on Caffe webpage. I think "-gpu 0" is also valid. Please check it out.

Comment: thank you again! I'm not sure if i should ask this as another question, but is multi-core processing also executable by command?

Comment: @ytrewq No, you don't need to do anything in command-line while using multi-core processing. You just have to enable openBlas in MakeFile.config

Answer (score 0):

This ipython notebook example explains the steps to extract features out of any caffe model really well: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb

In pycaffe, you can set gpu mode simply by using caffe.set_mode_gpu().